# Add video to beamer slide

Tags: beamer, animations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedding videos and animations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations)

I am new at making presentations using Latex (Beamer). What I need is to add some videos in my presentation. How can this be done?
Also, are there PDF readers which can play videos? If yes, then suggest which one preferably on Ubuntu (Windows is ok too). If no, then I can make do with an external media player playing the video.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations answer your questions?

Comment: Yes. It does! Wonder why it did not appear in the similar questions list when I asked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, then we can close this question as a duplicate.