# Animations with movie15 and swf files

Tags: animations, movie15, swf

I am trying to use `movie15` to embed vector animations in my presentation. The trouble is that embedded SWF files refuse to display on Acrobat Reader X sometimes with a "This Media requires an additional player" message. Eg. this [example file](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/movieExample/movie-swf.pdf) doesn't work.
Animated GIFs won't display either, with no error message.

Maybe this is an Acrobat issue but I tried the `flashmovie` package with the same SWF files and that *does* work (but only with the embedded player option so no controls are visible). But `flashmovie` is supposedly unstable with `beamer` so I was wondering if someone had run into the same problem with `movie15`.

I am using Windows 7, Acrobat 10.1.2 and MiKTeX.

Answer (score 30):

The replacement package is available on CTAN. It is called [`media9`](http://ctan.org/pkg/media9) and [documented on CTAN](http://ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf).

Use the MiKTeX or TeXLive package managers for installation.

A simple example embedding an SWF would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9} % only for latex->dvipdfmx

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,height=150pt,
]{}{myexample.swf}
\end{document}
```

A minimal example for embedding a video file, using the video player component `VPlayer.swf` shipping with `media9` and using the `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `latex`-->`dvips`-->`ps2pdf` or `latex->dvipdfmx`/`xelatex` work-flows would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9} % only for latex->dvipdfmx

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,height=150pt,
  addresource=Sample.mp4,
  flashvars={%
     source=Sample.mp4% same path as in addresource!
%   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
%   &loop=true%        % variables
  }  
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Video files must be in the `MP4` format. Videos in other formats must be converted to `MP4`, or recreated from the raw material. The `H.264` codec gives high quality video at stunningly small file size. With `ffmpeg`, video files can be created easily.

From an existing video file, such as `Sample.avi`, re-encoded with 30 frames (entered on a single command line):

```
ffmpeg -i Sample.avi -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"
    -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p
    -g 30 -r 30 video.mp4
```

From a numbered sequence of bitmaps, such as `frame-0.png`, `frame-1.png`, ... :

```
ffmpeg -i frame-%d.png -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"
    -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p
    -g 30 -r 30 Sample.mp4
```

Comment: Could you give MWE for inclusion avi movie? Should I use VPlayer.swf to play avi?

Comment: Avi cannot be played by FlashPlayer. You should convert all your video files into MP4, preferably using the H.246 codec, or better recreate them from the raw material (numbered sequence of PNG/JPEG or uncompressed video). You can use VPlayer.swf as a video player or any other player available on the net. I recommend open-source StrobeMediaPlayback.swf from Adobe, hosted on SourceForge.net.

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I used Nero Recode to convert my original `avi` to `mp4`.

Comment: When I follow these instructions, it compiles but Acrobat spits a window with the message "A 3D data parsing error has occurred.". (Acrobat Reader 9.5.1 Linux, pdflatex from TeXLive 2013, media9 v0.7)

Comment: I got same PDF error as `alfC`'s above.

Comment: @YanKingYin : Therefore, read: [Did anyone succeed in playing embedded movies inside Acrobat in Linux?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70931) .

Comment: I hate to be pedantic but my computer is! Your first (simple) example should have a square closing bracket instead of a curly one as thus: `]{}{myexample.swf}`. Your second example does not need correcting. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: >28k views and nobody has noticed before; thank you!