# How to use vlc as an `externalviewer' in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I have generated an avi file with matlab and it turned out that QuickTime was not able to play it. VLC was able to play it.

My objective is to include this avi file in my presentation using beamer. I'd prefer the avi to be embedded; if it is not possible, I'd like at least to play it externally. Hence, I wanted to use the `externalvierwer' vlc to play it. Here is the code I entered

```
     \movie[height=4cm,width=8cm,externalviewer]{}{example.avi}
```

When reading the pdf file in adobe reader 10.1.3, it only gives me the possibility to play the avi file by using

```
     QuickTime Player.app
```

It does not give me other possibilities such as vlc, or QuickTime Player 7.app which are installed and launched.

So how can I play my avi file using vlc from acrobat reader?

Comment: QuickTime is available on your system? Then you have either Win or Mac, and hence AdobeReader-X with embedded media playback is available. Try the `media9` package. To get you started look into instructions given [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47116/1053).

Comment: Maybe you have to change the file associations in your OS.

Comment: Thanks for the answers,
Yes QuickTime is available on my system. VLC and QuickTime Player 7 are available too. And I'm using Mac os 10.7.
I'll try media9 and let you know.

Is there any other solution using 
      multimedia package and \movie instruction

Comment: `multimedia` package is somewhat outdated, but perhaps the only choice if you want to use an open-source PDF viewer, such as Evince or Okular. (Package `movie15` may work as well.) Moreover the video file remains separate from the PDF when using `multimedia` (although being played in an embedded fashion).

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexG.
While using media9, I'm getting an error which I described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65342/compilation-error-media-9-package). I could not figure out where it comes from!!!

Comment: You should (re)consider the suggestion of @Jellby. Playing a file in an externalviewer is a matter of the OS that have to choose the right (or first) player using the file extension. Another solution might be to convert your avi file in another movie type.