# Compilation error with media9 package

Tags: errors, media9

While using `media9` package, I'm getting the following error :

```
Argument of \bool_if:nTF has an extra }
```

I'm unable to figure out where does the error come from. Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{media9}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includemedia[
    activate=pageopen,
    width=200pt,height=150pt,
    addresource=c4.mp4,
    flashvars={%
            source=c4.mp4
    }  
]{}{VLC.app}%{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You must use most recent `l3kernel`, `l3packages` and `media9` packages. Update your TeX distribution. If you have TeXLive-2012, run `tlmgr update --self --all`. You cannot use VLC with this method. If you want a player with controls, use `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf`. See media9 package documentation and the examples therein. Note that source setting via flashvars for Strobe is slightly different from VPlayer. `VPlayer.swf` and `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` are part of `media9`.

Comment: @AlexG This looks like a bug to me. Line 772 of `media9.sty` (v0.8) has `\msg_error:nnxx{media9}{file~not~found}{#1}`, but this should be `\msg_error:nnx{media9}{file~not~found}{#1}` (or probably the new `\msg_error:nnn`).

Comment: Thanks again @AlexG.
I've updated all the packages and I'm yet getting the same error. Is it due to the fact that the file (in my code VLC.app) is not found?

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph. I'll upload a corrected version. Will the x-variants be removed? How to ensure expansion of the argument if, for instance, the user provides a macro with the file name?

Comment: @AlexG The variants will be retained: we have simply 'tidied up' the definitions such that they are now based 'properly' on n-type base functions. Of course, if you allow names to be stored in macros then you do want the x-type variant.

Comment: Thanks @AlexG. Should I wait for a bug correction or can I do it myself on my Mac?

Comment: VLC.app simply cannot be used. Instead you need a media player as a Flash component, such as VPlayer.swf or StrobeMediaPlayback.swf.

Comment: Thanks @AlexG. I changed VLC.app to VPlayer.swf (and I've tried also StrobeMediaPlayback.swf) and yet I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Please put `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`. Recompile, open *.log and paste the list below `*File List*` into your question above. The bug @Joseph pointed out has nothing to do with the error you reported, as minimal examples with required files present work on my end.

Comment: @AlexG, the file c4.mp4 was missing in my directory. It provoked that bug. Even after adding the file in the right directory, I cannot get my video played yet!!! Instead I'm getting some strange characters in the slide. I'll post the log file in a wile.

Comment: @AlexG, sorry could not past the log file because it contains more than 30 000 characters.

Comment: Not the complete log file, only the file list. Try a basic example using `article` instead of `beamer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Joseph Wright pointed out, I can confirm that this is a bug in `media9.sty`, if you replace `"\msg_error:nnxx{media9}{file~not~found}{#1}"` by `"\msg_error:nnn{media9}{file~not~found}{#1}"`, there will be no error. However this points out to the fact that your file 'c4.mp4' doesn't exists or is not found.