# Launch video from pdf

Tags: viewers, adobe, multimedia

I am using package `multimedia` to insert videos into my PDF document using the command:

```
\movie[externalviewer]{Caption}{moviefile}
```

which works fine. My problem is that when I click on the caption I receive a warning message from Adobe Reader before the video launches:

> The file and its viewer application are set to be launched by this PDF file. The file may contain programs, macros, or viruses that could potentially harm your computer. Only open the file if you are sure it is safe. If this file was placed by a trusted person or program, you can click Open to view the file.

I understand the security reasons for the error message, but I am giving a presentation with a number of external videos and I would like to disable this message.

I realise this is probably more to do with Adobe Reader and not Latex, but I hoped someone here might be able to help?

I'm using Adobe Reader X Version 10.1.4

Comment: Since you have AR-X, why don't you use the `media9` package?

Comment: I've just looked into `media9` and converted my .avi files to .mp4 with Miro Video Converter. Videos now play well within the PDF. Thanks!

Comment: You can play multiple videos in the same video box by adding `\PushButton`s (package hyperref), each of which setting the `source` FlashVar of `VPlayer.swf` to a different video file when clicked (see example in `media9` doc). You can play external video files from the local hard disk by setting up a lightweight webserver, such as "nginx" (see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73039/1053) discussion).

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by the OP:

Since the viewer being used Adobe Reader-X, it is suggested that one uses `media9` package. From the [package description](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) at CTAN:

> The pack­age pro­vides an in­ter­face to em­bed in­ter­ac­tive Flash (SWF) and 3D ob­jects (Adobe U3D & PRC), as well as video and sound files or streams in the pop­u­lar MP4, FLV and MP3 for­mats into PDF doc­u­ments with Acro­bat-9/X com­pat­i­bil­ity.

This package eliminates the pop-up message by providing compatible interface. Please note the suggested formats for the audio and video files.