# How to Insert Playable Videos into Beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, embedding, video

I'm fairly new to LaTex and have to construct a beamer presentation. As part of my presentation, I want to include three videos side by side. To try to figure out how to do this, I have been scouring the internet looking for help. While doing that, I came across this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89088/how-to-embed-video-and-animation-in-latex-and-latex-beamer-step-by-step). However, when I tried to implement those suggestions, they still didn't seem to play properly. The code for the specific frame is included below - note that I previously had the presentation on PowerPoint and saved each of the videos as .mp4 files and their starting images as .png files. My two attempts are shown below:

```
\begin{frame}{movie}
\frametitle{Experiments}
\begin{figure}
      \raggedleft
       \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,height=.1\textwidth] 
            {parameters.png}
\end{figure}
\large \underline{Water/SDS} \newline
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
       \centering Heading A
       \includemedia[label      = AA,
                    width      = \linewidth,
                    height     = 20mm,
                    activate   = pageopen]{\includegraphics{video1.png}} 
        {video1.mp4}
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering Heading B
        \includemedia[label      = BB,
                     width      = \linewidth,
                     height     = 20mm,
                     activate   = pageopen]{\includegraphics{video2.png}} 
        {video2.mp4}
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
       \centering Heading C
       \includemedia[label      = BB,
                     width      = \linewidth,
                     height     = 20mm,
                     activate   = pageopen]{\includegraphics{video3.png}} 
        {video3.mp4}
 \end{minipage}}
 \end{frame}
```

This compiles fine and appears exactly as I want it to. The problem is the videos don't actually play. I also tried just using something like:

```
 \begin{frame}
 \movie[externalviewer]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{video1.png}} 
         {video1.mp4}
 \movie[externalviewer]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{video2.png}} 
         {video2.mp4}
 \movie[externalviewer]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{video2.png}} 
         {video2.mp4}
 \end{frame}
```

Again, all three images pop up next to each other like I would want, however, again they won't actually play. Is there something obvious I'm missing or doing wrong? And/or does anyone know how I can fix this? Appreciate any advice!

Also just to mention I do include:

```
 \usepackage{multimedia}
 \usepackage{media9}
 \addmediapath{./Movies/}
```

at the top of my .tex document. Should I have anything else?

Comment: playing videos in pdf is highly dependent on the pdf viewer (many can not do that at all) which pdf viewer are you using?

Comment: ah that's probably my issue then. I'm simply viewing the pdf via the internet. is there anything I can get for free to do this? if not, then is there anything I can cheap to fix this? - as always appreciate the help

Comment: The documentation to the `media9` packages says: "Adobe Reader, version ≥ 9, but not greater than 9.4.1 on Linux; Foxit Reader (Flash, video, audio)". The problem is obvously that playing videos in PDF needs Flash which is no longer supported.

Comment: Also see [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029/47927) about post-Flash video embedding into PDFs.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this working by using Acrobat to open my document.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345433/36296 for a list of compatible pdf viewer