# Beamer Multimedia package

Tags: beamer, animations, media9, multimedia

I have written the following document

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usetheme[hideallsubsections]{Berkeley}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\title[]{{\scshape Infodag wiskunde}}
\date{{\scshape 16 maart 2013}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\label{chaosfrag1}\frametitle{{\scshape Chaos 1 - }}
\begin{center}
\movie[showcontrols]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{chaos1.png}}{chaos1.mpg}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For some reason however, neither Adobe Reader nor Foxit PDF Reader are able to display the movie on click. I figured the issue was probably with the pdf readers, but last year I made a similar document, and though I no longer have the TeXcode, I still have the pdf, and this does work. (the embedded media there is also `.mpg`).
I already tried different media types (`.avi`, `.mp4`, .`flv`) but none of them work.

I know about the `media9` package, however, as my final document will contain about 18 movies of each 10 minutes, the resulting pdf would be 2GB. Whenever I open it, it takes at least 10 seconds to start playing the media, and even then, it doesn't work (I just get a gray rectangle).

EDIT: Okay, appearantly i was using a wrong code for media9, so now I can play the video (though the filesize still is huge). But still, it would be nice to see if I made a mistake somewhere in the `\movie` command or something...

I hope someone can help :)

Comment: You may try to run a lightweight web server, such as `nginx`, on your presentation laptop. This allows you to play video files from the local hard disc instead of embedded ones using the `media9` package. Loading is much faster then, because files don't need be extracted and decompressed. Read on [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72993).

Comment: I personally never use embedded video in my beamer presentation: I use always external viewers (VLC) to play the movies. The advantages are that the PDF is smaller and I am not limited by the codecs. The main inconvenient is that you have to keep to all the files at the right place...

Comment: @AlexG : I'm not sure I get what you mean. I was currently using
    `\includemedia[
  addresource=chaos1.mp4,
  flashvars={
    source=chaos1.mp4
   &autoPlay=true
   &scaleMode=letterbox
  }
]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{chaos1.png}}{VPlayer.swf}`

But this still embeds into the pdf (pdf size is still huge).

Comment: Option `addresource=...` embeds the video file, and FlashVar `source=...` lets `VPlayer.swf` know what to play. What you want is `source=http://localhost/chaos1.mp4` without `addresource` (no embedding). For this to work you will have to run a web server, as explained in the topic linked in my first comment.

Comment: Alternatively, you may upload the video file to a file sharing service, such as dropbox, and set `source` to the remote URL of the video file. Playback will start while a large video file is still being downloaded.

Comment: Could somebody please provide a working minimal example with source code and compiled PDF?

Comment: @moose: Using what, `multimedia` or `media9`?

Comment: If possible, for both one example. And I would really like to add them to my [LaTeX example repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/).

Comment: @moose: `multimedia` example see below. `media9` example with external (not embedded) video file, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73039/1053).

Comment: @AlexG: Both answer do not contain the compiled PDF.

Comment: @moose: In this forum file attachments are not possible.

Comment: There are [many services](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=where+can+i+upload+files) where you can upload files. If you don't like any of them you could sent them to me (info@martin-thoma.de) and I'll post a link to them in my GitHub repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `multimedia`, only videos in the AVI format, encoded using one of the standard codecs available on Windows (MS Video 1, Full Frames (Uncompressed)) will successfully play on Windows. MPEG does definitely *not* work.

```
\movie{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{chaos1.png}}{chaos1.avi}
```

I successfully produced an AVI from a BMP sequence using `pjBmp2Avi.exe` and selecting 'MS Video 1'.

Comment: I will probably have used a wrong codec, but still, will probably use your nginx solution! Thanks :)

Comment: This answer really helped steer me in the right direction when I was having a problem with this issue..thank you!  Some things to add:  Using Windows 7 with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.  I could get videos in the AVI container to work.  The only audio codec I had success with was "pcm_u8" (PCM unsigned 8-bit).  For the video codec, success came after I downloaded the "ffdshow" codec package (from SourceForge) to the Windows machine and activated just ffdshow's "Other MPEG4" format (which included the needed "FMP4" codec (FYI, `ffmpeg` calls this "mpeg4 (Simple Profile))".  Running out of room...

Comment: (continuation from the above comment)  FYI, videos that were "cropped" at the beginning did not work until I placed the `-ss` option in *front* of the input file specification (FWIW, this was when using Beamer's Multimedia package's "poster" option).

Comment: I can say that the "rawvideo" ffmpeg video codec works, but, of course, the resultant video files are huge when using this.  Will report later if the cinepak codec works.

Comment: Why don't you use package `media9` and embed H.264 video?

Comment: @AlexG - I'm trying to have success with the multimedia package.

Comment: I can report that with the above-mentioned setup (Windows 7 with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC), I found two additional audio codecs that work: "_adpcm_ima_wav_" (ADPCM IMA WAV) and "_adpcm_ms_" (ADPCM Microsoft).

Comment: FYI, in order to get the videos to play on a Windows 7 machine, I needed to add "Everyone" to the "Group or user names" of one of the parent folders.