# Size of video in media9 package (is there a upper limit?)

Tags: media9

I was trying to insert two video into LaTeX using `media9`. However one appeared while the other did not. Both of them in MP4 format. The one that appeared is below 100 MB, while the one that did not appeared successfully is above 100 MB.

Thus I was wondering is `media9` has a upper limit for video embedding?

Comment: Thanks so much for refining my question!!!!!!! @Joseph Wright

Answer (score 1):

Embedded videos must be *completely* extracted and uncompressed *before* they can be played by the FlashPlayer plugin. This may take a while for such large video files.

Alternatively, video files can be streamed from a URL which may turn out to be faster in the case of large files, since playback already starts after partial download. Extraction from PDF doesn't take place here.

Video files may be served by a locally running web server. See   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73039 .