# GIF/SWF animation embedded in LaTeX document (PDF)

Tags: pdftex, pdf, animations, examples

There seem to be plenty of resources for how to do it (even on this website), but I'm struggling with the process.

Can someone provide a link to an **example** pdf with the working animations in it? The only I see have buttons and are interactive (but aren't working on my machine anyway)-- what I would like is even simpler, just a looping gif file that never stops (I'm trying to show the evolution of a system, against certain parameters and time).

Thanks for any examples.

Comment: See the `animate` package: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate Gif files cannot be included in pdf files. For Swf, the animate package does it as well.

Comment: And also here [Animations with movie15 and swf files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45242/animations-with-movie15-and-swf-files)

Comment: Steps for a 100 frames animated gif, using package `animate` and playing at 12 frames per s: (1) `gifsicle --unoptimize animated.gif | convert - frame-%d.png` (2) `\animategraphics[loop,autoplay]{12}{frame-}{0}{99}`.