# Video from Beamer Plays Only One Second

Tags: beamer, pdftex, multimedia

Sorry about the title...it was hard to word my problem.

I am using LaTeX, and more specifically Beamer, to create a presentation that plays a video file. The code I use is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{frame}
  \movie[width=6cm,height=4cm,showcontrols]{}{Movie.avi}
\end{frame}
...
\end{document}
```

This compiles with pdfLaTeX all dandy, but whenever I try to view the video file in Adobe Reader on Windows 7, the video plays about one second, stops, then returns to the start ready to be played again. It's like either LaTeX or Adobe Reader thinks the video is only one second long.

I tried adding the duration tag to \movie. I also tried changing around all the security configurations within Reader. The video files are in the same directory as the pdf and the tex files from compilation to viewing. Anyone have any advice as to what I might check next?

Comment: Videos embedded with `multimedia` require a third party plug-in for playback within AR. There may either be a problem with the plug-in or with the video file. I suggest switching to the `media9` package, which provides more reliable media playback because it uses Adobe's FlashPlayer plug-in. The second code example in this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47116) may help you. You have to recode the video file into MP4/H.264 format for use with `media9`. And the FlashPlayer plugin for Firefox (not for IE!) must be installed.