# Cannot insert the video in beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, video

I was following the example

[Animations with movie15 and swf files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45242/animations-with-movie15-and-swf-files?answertab=active#tab-top)

trying to insert my video into beamer presentation. This is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9} % only for latex->dvipdfmx

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,height=150pt,
  addresource=plane_pol.mp4,
  flashvars={%
     source=plane_pol.mp4% same path as in addresource!
%   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
%   &loop=true%        % variables
 }   
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

The output is [image]

I am working from Mac. Maybe there is something uninstalled... Have no idea. Please, help!

Comment: `preview` does not support all features, try with adobe reader.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because viewer issue