# Embedding videos in a Beamer presentation with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, luatex, media9, video

I am trying to embed a video using the `media9` package for a Beamer presentation. Because I use a special font, I need to compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Now to do this video embedding you need to make a dvi file rather than a pdf file. But LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX both directly make a pdf file. It is possible to get a dvi file with LuaLaTeX by either using the `--output-format=dvi` option or the `dvilualatex` command, but in both cases the compiler can't find my figures... As for XeLaTeX, I can only ouput xdv files.

So my question is this, is there a way to make it work with LuaLaTeX or embed the video via a xdv file with XeLaTeX? Otherwise are there any simple alternatives?

Comment: well video embedding is a problem since flash support was removed in the pdf viewers (and probably it won't work anymore with media9 unless you have an old reader), but I'm not aware that dvi is more usefull. Where did you get that info from?

Comment: I used this question for the procedure: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45242/animations-with-movie15-and-swf-files

Comment: that's a 2012 answer, you are unlikely to have a pdf reader that can still do that (and if you have you  probably shouldn't use it as you haven't had a securirty update in a decade)

Comment: well apart that the answer is old and probably don't work anyway: it doesn't say that you need dvi. It actually explicitly say that it works with all workflows.

Comment: keep the video separate and just link to it from the beamer file, that will give much better experience than trying to find a pdf viewer that can still embed video in the pdf.

Comment: I tried Fritz's answer in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio but I get the following error message... "<recently read> \pdf_pageobject_ref:n
l.340 \end{frame}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed." I can't comment there because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: Ah! It wasn’t and now it works, thanks!!