# Is it possible to open a video file via a link in beamer？

Tags: beamer, pdf, links, linux, animations

I have searched through posts like "embedded video in PDF", it seems that this feature is only available in Adobe Acrobat.

So I just thought the alternative solution: open a video file (using system default video player, e.g VLC video player) via the links of photo or text in the beamer slides, in this way one doesn't have to exit the beamer presentation to open a video file and do a lot switching things.

If this is possible, how to make it?

[OS: Linux Ubuntu, PDF viewer: evince]

**Edit1:**

```
 \usepackage{multimedia}
 ...
 \movie{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{pic.png}}{movieSample.avi}
```

Compile without error, but seems there is no link (envice in linux) for the photo to open movie.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is possible. See also the answer by Predrag Punosevac here: [Embedding videos and animations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations)

He makes use of a script that launches the media player he has installed (MPlayer):

```
\begin{center}
\href{run:/usr/local/bin/mplayer -fs forced_pendulum.mp4}{
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]
{forced_pendulum.eps}}
\end{center}
```

This works, but only on your system and others configured exactly like it. User Canageek suggests calling the default player instead of using the entire path.

Bottom line: it's possible, but you need to fiddle around a bit with the path/command to get it right according to your preferences.

Comment: thanks @Emiel! I stored the videos in the same folder (or sub-folder) of the beamer file, so how to get the `file path` automatically. Besides, how to open the video file in `Windows` system?

Comment: I tried `hyperref` solution, but the PDF viewer `envince` complains: `Unable to launch external application. Error when getting information for file '/usr/bin/vlc ~/tex/x.mov': No such file or directory`, where the movie file is set as the absolute path. Even adobe reader 9 fails

Comment: See this for the right way to do it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132867/1871

Comment: for me it worked to simply store the video in the same folder and execute it with this command: `\href{run:./myVideo.mp4}{Start Video}`