# video embedding in TeX Live

Tags: beamer

I have to make videos. It can be done using different software available but I want to make it using LaTeX. Can anyone tell how to make videos using TeX Live and wined t editor.

Comment: Yeah.so can you tell me exact steps or how to start?? What is the document class used for making videos.

Comment: How about [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2869/19356)?

Comment: Is your editor WinEdt?

Comment: Unless you're talking about [embedding videos that have already been made](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574), I believe this is well outside the scope of what TeX was designed to do. For all intents and purposes, video generation with TeX is impossible.

Comment: @SeanAllred: [never say impossible...](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/i-tex-therefore-i-toast/)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Nice link (but seriously, pretty awesome—a nice laugh), but I would say that's very different from what OP seems to be asking.  GPIO on the Pi is controlled via plain-text file writes—something TeX can do with relative ease. Videos… not so much ;-)

Comment: @SeanAllred: absolutely right, but you know: ancient romans would have considered impossible to talk in real time from Thrace to Rome... now we have smartphones ;)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino (In my best sketchy internet advertisement voice:) *Has science gone too far?*