# href keyboard shortcut

Tags: beamer, keyboard, shortcut, href

I am using the href package within a beamer presentation to run a videofile in VLC player. Instead of having some "clickable item" in the pdf (a button, image, or text), I would like to run the video (i.e. "click on the link") with a button on the keyboard. What I am looking for is a way to show a slide with a still from the following video and then simply to click some keyboard button and the video will launch (in VLC).

How would I go about this? Can somebody give me advice or point me into the right direction?

Comment: Isn't this automatic? See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations

Comment: Which viewer do you use? Some may be easier to configure keyboard actions in than others. Or you can 'cheat' by opening VLC in the background and switching with `alt`-`tab` or assign a custom keyboard shortcut (see, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/questions/180312/is-it-possible-to-assign-shortcuts-to-launch-applications for Ubuntu).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. However, what I am trying to do is the following. Instead using the movie9 or multimedia package, I want to open the video in VLC player. I use href to "run the video file". This works nicely, because I have VLC setup in a way that it goes fullscreen on start and quits the program after the end. All I want to achieve is triggering "the href link" (that runs the video file) with a keyboard button instead of having to click on it with the mouse. The reason behind this is that I want to map a button on my presenter remote control to that keyboard button.

Comment: In some pdf viewers this may be possible, in others not, which pdf viewer do you use? Adobe Reader, Evince, Okular, Sumatra, something else?

Comment: Thank you Marijn. I am using Skim. How would I do it Skim or any of the viewers that you mention?