# How to embed a video

Tags: multimedia, video

I would like to embed a video in a pdf that starts and stops playing by using the mouse to click the buttons

[image]

Following

[Embedding videos and animations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations?answertab=active#tab-top)

I devised a code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \movie{movie}{penguins.mp4} %from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9iXD2-hbJM 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I get is a page

[image]

that does not contain the slightest hint of the embedded movie. How to improve this solution?

Comment: What about `\movie{\includegraphics{AMdWB}}{penguins.mp4}`? (Using https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMdWB.png)

Comment: @AlexG those are actual buttons that I should be able to click with a mouse.

Comment: If you click them, the video should start playing, provided you are using the right PDF viewer.

Comment: @AlexG I use okular

Comment: Well, what happens if you click?

Comment: @AlexG nothing at all

Comment: But it should :(. Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345431 ?

Comment: @AlexG I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: Is `penguins.mp4` in the same directory as the PDF?

Comment: @AlexG, yes it is

Comment: Try other pdf viewers like evince to see if that is the issue

Comment: @jsb, with evince the movie plays by clicking on the placeholder. A separate OpenGL window opens. But I am not able to replay the movie, nor pause and resume.