# Embedding videos in Beamer presentation under Linux (Fedora 30)

Tags: beamer, linux, embedding, video, linuxfedora

This is a common question but frankly, there seems not to be an easy successful way to do it. All the resources that I found do not work. Including, I cannot reproduce videos in PDF files by Okular on my Fedora 30. Can you folks write down a "definite" concise and clear guide, if possible? I know that this might be subjected to the Linux Distro. So in my case I am working in Fedora 30.

These are the resources I looked into:

- [Andrew J. Berry's original guide](https://abarry.org/the-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/) (refers to use Adobe Acrobat
  Reader 9.4.1 -- dropped it: too obsolete).
- [Andrew J. Berry's new guide](https://abarry.org/the-new-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/) (a headache)
- [SE classic page 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations) (does not provide a
  working solution)
- [SE classic page 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer) (refers to `media9` package
  which again seems to work with AR 9.4.1 which makes a joke to install
  a 10-year-old software on Linux 2020 that Adobe even discontinued,
  and also relies on the Flash plugin which is going to be discontinued
  this year).
- [Overleaf example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_can_I_embed_a_video_in_my_PDF_using_LaTeX%3F) (which does not work for me,
  despite following the instructions on the link).

*For speculators*:
Why something so fundamental like including multimedia and videos in a PDF presentation, has to be such a nightmare in Beamer (under Linux)?

Comment: Currently, the most portable way to have presentations with embedded multimedia is the SVG format. SVG with multimedia can be viewed in a variety of Web browsers that are available across all popular operating systems and platforms. I am about finalizing a multimedia inclusion package for the `dvisvgm` back-end.

Comment: The problem is not the distribution or Latex, the problem is the reader. As far as I know, only the Adobe reader is capable to reproduce multimedia embedded in a PDF (this may be a licensing issue, hence no other reader do that). So, of you don't want to deal with Acrobat reader you better find a different way to create your presentation.

Comment: @SalatielGarcia : That's why, as I said before, SVG might be a good substitute for PDF, in particular for presentation-type documents. Full-featured web browsers a ubiquitous, as compared to PDF viewers.

Comment: So the conclusion I am taking out of this is: leave it and plan your PDF without videos or multimedia if you are working with Beamer on Linux?

Comment: Once the promised pkg is ready, `beamer`-class documents in SVG format with embedded videos can easily produced and viewed under Linux. Pkg `animate` already supports SVG, as can be seen here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235180 .

Comment: @AlexG It is promising. But there are some issues: `animate` allows me to import SVG "movies" as if I were building GIFs, but if I want to include an MP4 file or an audio file, there is no way that I know of to convert them into SVG.

Comment: @maurizio : The pkg is ready and will be available in TeXLive-2020 within the next days:  https://ctan.org/pkg/media4svg

Comment: @AlexG Thanks. I am going to test it.

Comment: And how about this (https://pdfpc.github.io/)

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL it works. But you folks should mention that there is a restriction on the type of file to embed, which is inherited by the `multimedia` package. Only if I have my videos in MPEG-2 then I can reproduced them.

Comment: @AlexG I downloaded the `media4svg` from CTAN but it seems bugged. Or some of my packages are clashing. Where can I send you a log so maybe you can help me figure out how to make it work?

Comment: @maurizio Would you mind asking a new question, with a compilable example added? Would be great, as it would be the first `media4svg` question on TeXSX. It would perhaps help to popularize it somewhat.

Comment: @AlexG https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548137/compilation-error-embedding-figures-by-media4svg-in-beamer

Comment: @maurizio I think the only solution for the various video formats would be to use Adobe Acrobat :( ... converting them or using 'media4svg' is the best "multi-platform" option at the moment

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Fedora (30,31,32), this has worked for me:

Install `pdfpc`

```
sudo dnf -y install pdfpc
```

Check if you have installed `gstreamer1-plugins-good-gtk`, If not, you install it:

```
sudo dnf -y install gstreamer1-plugins-good-gtk
```

You can try it out by downloading [an example with movies](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc/releases/latest/download/pdfpc-video-example.zip) from https://pdfpc.github.io/

Using TeXLive 2020 to work for me.

PS: It also works in Win10 :)