# Compilation error embedding figures by media4svg in beamer

Tags: beamer, linux, svg, embedding, video

I am experimenting with the new promising package `media4svg` which supposedly allows me to embed videos in a `beamer` presentation almost effortlessly, and then play the presentation in a common modern browser. This possibility actually would also allow for sharing presentations smoothly. For example, I am working on `Fedora 30+` and because of Wayland, a common conference tool like `zoom` has limited sharing screen options, allowing me to share only one screen. if I play my presentation by `pdfpc` the video will be automatically skipped and the next slide loaded. So if I can make `media4svg` work and use my browser I would actually solve two problems at once. Bottom line, I am compiling from command line:

```
dvilualatex myfile.tex
```

and I get some strange errors:

```
Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex' and `luatex' are not supp
orted.

))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarypositioning.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.multipart.code.tex)) (/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/media4svg/media4svg.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)...exlive/texmf-dist
/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-package.lua:286: error loading module media4svg fro
m file /home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/media4svg/media4svg.lua:
    /home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/media4svg/media4svg.lua:60: unexpected symbol n
ear '>'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'path specification'
    ...exlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-package.lua:286: in function '
?'
    ...exlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-package.lua:318: in function <
...exlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-package.lua:310>
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
<argument> \directlua {require('media4svg')}

l.731 ..._luatex:T{\directlua{require('media4svg')}}
```

Could it be I am clashing with something? Or maybe I am hitting a bug? This question should have tag `media4svg` but I do not have enough reputation to add this tag. Sorry.

Thanks.

Comment: I can also confirm that the same error occurs using the cloned package from [git](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media4svg).

Comment: I am using a full vanilla TeXLive-2020 from tug.org, installed in my home directory. Which distribution do you use? TeXLive installations as part of Linux distributions are often outdated or incomplete.

Comment: Could you please add a down-stripped, yet complete (i. e. compilable) version of `myfile.tex`?

Comment: @AlexG Hi Alex, thanks. Actually this happens also with your example on the repo. Same error. And as you hint, it might be related to the texlive version: I am using TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018) kpathsea version 6.3.0, which is delivered with Fedora 30. I know I should probably upgrade by now to Fedora 32, which I believe has TeX Live 2020 probably, but I cannot at the moment due to limitations of my machine. Any workaround or biocompatibility suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: You don't need to update your Linux system. I recommend to install the [current TeXLive version from TUG](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz) as a normal user in your home directory. (Which I always do.) You just have to adjust the PATH environment after installation to have `~/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux` (or similar) in front of other TeX directories. A private installation can peacefully coexist with a Linux distro-provided TeXLive installation. Installation instructions: http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: @AlexG Thanks. I am going to test it then as you say. Allow me few days. I should be able to follow up during the week.

Comment: No problem. Just take the time you need.